# Tus.io WebException (Server Error 460) During Normal Upload

Tags: vb.net, transloadit, resume-upload

I'm using Tus.io (Resume-able File Upload Library) .Net Client library to upload files to a web server.

Here is the code snippet:

```
 Dim testfile = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("..\..\test.pptx")

    Dim tc As New TusClient.TusClient()
    AddHandler tc.Uploading, Sub(bytesTransferred As Integer, bytesTotal As Integer)
                                 Dim perc As Decimal = bytesTransferred / bytesTotal * 100.0
                                 Console.WriteLine("Up {0:0.00}% {1} of {2}", perc, bytesTransferred, bytesTotal)
                             End Sub

    Dim fileURL = tc.Create(ServerURL, testfile)

    tc.Upload(fileURL, testfile)
```

Upload functions works well for small files e.g. 500kb file but not for the files with size 3MB or greater. It throws exception after transferring 100% data(As per % given by Uploading Event).

**Exception: WebException**

Message: The remote server returned an error: (460) Unknown.

Response Content: "Header Upload-Checksum does not match the checksum of the file"

Status: ProtocolError {7}

Do let me know if any required information is missing here.
Any solution or quick workaround would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

PS. I couldn't add Tus.io tag due to limited privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tus.io .NET client library has included a "check-sum" header, which is causing the client to throw this error. Easiest solution right now is to remove or comment out the following line, recompile, and you would be good to go.

```
TusClient.cs
line 150: request.AddHeader("Upload-Checksum", "sha1 " + Convert.ToBase64String(sha1hash));
```